# My jQuery rotate function is working once

Tags: jquery, function, svg, rotation, click

I'm using jQuery transition function, here is the code

```
function rotate() {
$("#wiper").transition({ rotate: '360deg'},1000,'linear'); 
}

$(".about").click(function() 
{rotate()
});

$(".services").click(function() 
{rotate()
});
```

The rotate function is only working one time, when I click on "about" it works but after I click on services it is not working.

In the site I have added old codes they don't need reverse transition, only 360 degree transition they need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#wiper").transition({ rotate: '360deg'},1000,'linear', function(){ $(this).css('rotate', '0deg'); });
```

After the transition ends, the object has `style="rotate: 360deg;"`. So in the next click, the code doen't do anything because there is nothing to change. Is like use `animate({color: "red"})` on `<div style="color: red;"></div>`...